# Event returned as undefined for onSubmit() and onChange() for submit type form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a basic submit form, where the user enters the desired text and upon hitting enter or pressing the submit button the value in text box gets submitted. Here what my parent component looks like, I am passing handler functions as props to the child component.

```
<Toolbar
    drawerClickHandler={() => handleClickSideDrawer(isDisplaySideDrawer)}
    value={searchText}
    onChange={handleSearchChange}
    onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}
  />
```

Child Component:

```
const toolbar = (props) => {
return (
    <header className={styles.toolbar}>
        <nav className={styles.toolbar_navigation}>
            <div className={styles.spacer}>
                <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
                    <label className={styles.form_search_input}>
                        <input
                            className={styles.form_search_input_text}
                            type="text"
                            value={props.value}
                            onChange={props.onChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
);
```

}

My handlers functions are present in parent class and look like this :

```
const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
setSearchText(event.target.value);}

const handleSearchSubmit = (event) => {
alert('A name was submitted: ' + searchText);
event.preventDefault();}
```

Here on change event in test box the event variable comes as undefined. My understanding is event is a synthetic event which is fired by react, and I don't need to pass any value for it when I am passing handler function as props to child component I am missing something? I took reference from react official documentation for form creation :

Comment: Try changing the order of statements in `handleSearchSubmit`. use e.preventDefault() before the alert statement

Comment: Don't know if that would help, in react's official documentation they have used in the same order : [CodePen link] (https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010)

The only difference I can see is they have class component, but I am using functional component.